# How to find the file path of a Quarto-file when rendering it into a HTML-file in RStudio using the Knitr-engine?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, quarto

I need to find the path to a Quarto-file (from within just that file in RStudio) to check for existing directories. This worked well so far with `getSourceEditorContext()$path`. But as soon as I render the file into a HTML, RStudio throws an internal error message saying: *The system cannot find the file specified*.

Every other method (find assortment below) I tried to find the file's path returns an empty string instead of the path to the file I am calling the functions from. Is there any straight forward way to do this?

```
rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path
dirname(knitr::current_input())
dirname(knitr::opts_knit$get("input"))
commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1]
as.character(match.call())[2]
Sys.getenv("R_SCRIPT_PATH")
```

Comment: Do you want to find the path of the Quarto file being rendered? If so, `getwd()` should give you that.